# Printing a certain shape with python

Tags: python

I need to print a shape that looks like the following

```
*   *
*   *
 * *
  *
 * *
*   *
*   *
```

I've tried doing this but only managed to print an X shape

```
n = 7
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, n):
        if (i==j or j==n-1-i):
            print("*",end=" ")
        else:
            print(" ",end=" ")

    print()
```

output:

```
*           * 
  *       *   
    *   *     
      *       
    *   *     
  *       *   
*           *
```

Don’t know how to approach this and would like some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two lists with the number of spaces before the first `*` and the number between the two `*`s and then use `zip()` and f-strings:

```
before = [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0]
between = [3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3]
for i, j in zip(before, between):
    print(f'{i*" "}*{j*" "}{"*" if j  else ""}')
```

Output:

```
*   *
*   *
 * *
  *
 * *
*   *
*   *
```